# How to start cron in joomla with civicrm manually? Answer: use civicrm planned jobs!

Tags: joomla-3.x

Using Joonla 3.7 I used to get a warning about the cron job not running that's because my provider does not allow jobs

I could do the cronjob manually by clicking on the warning and all was fine to me

After updating Joomla to 3.8.3 I cannot find the link to cron manually

Can you please tell me if this can be done in the control-panel?

---

thank you for your reply.

sorry, I do not think I used a special plugin ; when logging in in Joomla we get the warning popup about cron:
*Cron Not Running
Last cron run at 7 december 2017 17:41 uur PM.
View details and manage alerts*

in the same popup klicking the link gave another page where I could run cron manually

maybe because in Joomla we have civicrm installed?

Comment: The Joomla CMS core has no inbuilt cron tasks to run, so I presume you're talking about a specific component or plugin that has a cron script to run?

Comment: Bingo. CiviCRM has a job queue that should be run with a Cron. You may find the answer to your question here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cron-job

Comment: @ "bingo" thank you!
problem solved: manually cron link can be found in civicrm planned jobs

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  Feel free to edit your question title, answer your own question, or delete the whole thing to make the question/answer useful for future users.

Comment: **Point of order.** @Rob this page has not been resolved properly.  When James asked you to edit your question, he did not mean to advise you to inject the resolution into the title.  Please take our [tour]. This page needs work.  The advice from the civicrm link should be used to craft a new answer on this page.  The answer should cater to the exact question being asked here.  The question should never contain its resolution. Pages are marked as resolved by awarding the big green tick to the best answer that resolves the question.  I hope that you will come back and help to tidy up this page.

Answer (score 0):

All PHP crons are activated by an URL.

You can simply determine which the task url for the cron you want to use and access by browser.

Anyway, in the net exists a lot of solutions to externally activate crons (knowing the url).